# VBA userform as variable in functions

Tags: vba, function, object, variables, userform

I have the following problem: I have a userform menu, from there I can navigate to other pages, and I want to create a "back button" for each page to return to the menu.

I tried to create this:

```
Private Sub btnback_Click()
Call back_menu(Actions)
End Sub

Sub back_menu(stage)  'Tried: stage As Object
    Unload stage
    Menu.Show
End Sub
```

Another example:

```
Sub next_page(from,to)
Unload from
to.show
```

This 1st is working now, but everytime I close the userform i got an error:

Run-type error'13'
Type missmatch

I know I could write one by one or I could us the Unload Me, but I have other Functions where I would like to use this method to call the right userform.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the `hide` method of the userform

```vb
Sub back_menu(stage as UserForm)  'Tried: stage As Object
    stage.hide
    Menu.Show
End Sub
```

```vb
Sub next_page(frmFrom as UserForm, frmTo as UserForm)
  frmFrom.hide
  frmTo.show
end Sub
```

You shoud avoid variable names that are code words as well --> like `to` in `For i = 1 to 10`.

Comment: Thanks, this hide method is working. Can you suggest something for this: 

Sub next_page(from,to)
Unload from
to.show

Comment: ähhhmmm .... shouldn't be too hard to adjust this based on my example ....

Comment: Tried with this but with the 2 varriable the error occur...  However it works.

Comment: I know I can't use "to" as varriable, it was just an example. I tried it and now it's not working  and I got an other error: Run-type error'438'  Object doesn't support this property or method

Comment: Are you really passing UserForms to the sub?

Comment: I would like to. I have a lot of userform and coding the mapping would be much easier.  Do you have any other ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: It is very hard to give you an advice without knowing about the project. I try to avoid userforms totally and put everything - on worksheets. Using hyperlinks to jump to different pages ... but that's too complex to explain here

Comment: Are you passing userform pages to the sub - then you have to check for those methods in the help

Comment: Long story short: Im creating testdata recorder and I choosed exel to do this. So when you open exel the userform open auto, in the menu page you can select system where you want to create testdata, then you select specific projekt then select you want to add/edit/del and then the right userform (this one is legit a form) open, you fill it or leave blank (blank will be autogenerated). End the end the exel has output CSV, that used by an API and send to the right system backend. Im not sure is it makes sense to you, but maybe help to understand my purpose.

Comment: My last comment on this: give it a try to rebuild the user forms on a worksheet - using named ranges, validation lists, hyperlinks to jump to another sheet or even to start a procecc etc. You will find a lot of tutorials for each topic

Comment: Thanks the tips and the answer as well.